# getting php session from javascript variable

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I am using a JQuery date and time picker in my php website. I want to save the javascript variable as a php session, I have looked at previous answers on this site and tried suggestions but it doesnt seem to be working for me. Can anyone tell me what Im missing?

This is my jquery date and time picker, getting the selected date and time, and the posting ajax:

```
<input type="text" name="date2" value="">
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function(){

$('*[name=date2]').appendDtpicker({"inline": true,
"allowWdays": [1, 2, 3, 4, 5], // 0: Sun, 1: Mon, 2: Tue, 3: Wed, 4: Thr, 5: Fri, 6: Sat
"futureOnly": true,
"autodateOnStart": false
});

$('#btn_input').on('click', function(){
    var input = $('*[name=date2]').handleDtpicker('getDate');
    console.log(input);
    jQuery.ajax({
        url: 'backend.php',
        type: 'POST',
        data: {
            'input': input,
        },
        dataType : 'json',
        success: function(data, textStatus, xhr) {
            console.log(data); // do with data e.g success message
        },
        error: function(xhr, textStatus, errorThrown) {
            console.log(textStatus.reponseText);
        }
    });
});
});

</script>
<input type="submit" class="btn" id="btn_input" value="Confirm">
```

And this is the backend.php i am sending it to:

```
<?php
session_start(); 
$_SESSION['input'] = $_POST['input'];
echo ($_SESSION['input']);
?>
```

Any help is much appreciated!

Comment: Do you have any errors?

Comment: Yes, sorry, when i open the backend.php page to see the echoed messaged it says thats its not recognising the $_POST['input'];

Comment: declare the input variable outside your click scope.. then just change the value of it within the click scope.

Comment: You also have an extra `});` above and a missing one after your `jQuery.ajax();`

Comment: I'm sorry im not sure what you mean, put the second script with the ajax post after the button and seperate from the button click function?

apologies im not too great with this

Comment: Thank you i added the one below but looks like i still need the one above, thanks for that! but still getting the error

Answer (score 1):

**New answer**:

HTML

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<!-- include jquery here -->
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.simple-dtpicker.js"></script>
<link type="text/css" href="jquery.simple-dtpicker.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
</head>
<body>
      <input type="text" class="myDatepicker"/>
</body>
</html>
```

JS

```
$(function(){
    $('.myDatepicker').appendDtpicker({ //please note that it requires an element that fits this selector
        'inline' : true,
        'allowWdays' : [1, 2, 3, 4, 5], 
        'futureOnly' : true,
        'autodateOnStart' : false
        'onHide': function(handler){
             $.ajax({
                type: 'POST',
                url: 'backend.php',
                data: 'input='+ handler.getDate(), //the selected value is being sent to your php, where the session variable is set accordingly
                success: function(response){
                     console.log(response); //in case you have any output (e.g. error messages) in backend.php we will output them to the console for debugging purposes.
                     }
                });
            }
        });
    });
```

PHP (backend.php)

```
 <?php
 session_start();
 $_SESSION['input'] = $_POST['input'];

 echo $_SESSION['input'];
 ?>
```

Complete script would typically look like:

index.php / index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<!-- include jquery here -->
</head>
<body>
      <input type="text" class="myDatepicker"/>
</body>
</html>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function(){
    $('.myDatepicker').appendDtpicker({ //please note that it requires an element that fits this selector
        'inline' : true,
        'allowWdays' : [1, 2, 3, 4, 5], 
        'futureOnly' : true,
        'autodateOnStart' : false
        'onHide': function(handler){
             $.ajax({
                type: 'POST',
                url: 'backend.php',
                data: 'input='+ handler.getDate(), //the selected value is being sent to your php, where the session variable is set accordingly
                success: function(response){
                     console.log(response); //in case you have any output (e.g. error messages) in backend.php we will output them to the console for debugging purposes.
                     }
                });
            }
        });
    });
</script>
```

Please note that the path to backend.php suggests that index.php/index.html and backend.php are located in the same folder.

**ORIGINAL ANSWER**: Originally I thought we were talking about jQuery-ui datepicker. I'll leave this response in case anyone needs it.

This is one way of doing it...

```
$('.myElement').datepicker({
     minDate: 0, //dates from today and onwards
     onSelect: function(date){ //"date" will have the selected value of the datepicker
        $.ajax({
           type: 'POST',
           url: 'backend.php',
           data: 'input='+ date, //the selected value is being sent to your php, where the session variable is set accordingly
           success: function(response){
                console.log(response); //in case you have any output (e.g. error messages) in backend.php we will output them to the console for debugging purposes.
                }
           });
      });
```

Comment: `data: 'input='+ data,`? Shouldn't be `data: {input: data},`?

Comment: Well, I admit that data was a poor choise of variable name. But, it's perfectly fine to send it like this `'input='+ date`. I'll change the variable name to date instead. Why the downvotes?

Comment: Hasn't the `data` property in `$.ajax()` **to be** an object? Can you pass string like so?

Comment: It works perfectly fine. You should try it if you are in doubts. For example using the jQuery serialize method will actually create a string like this `foo=bar&foo1=bar1`, etc.

Comment: Fair enough, thanks for the heads up. Just upvoted :)

Comment: I just tried this but i think the syntax is breaking the qjuery picker, 

for this i believe it must have to work with $('*[name=date2]').handleDtpicker('getDate');

Comment: Oh, wow.. you are actually using a library called Dtpicker (which I have never heard of). Sorry about the confusion. I just assumed you were using the jquery-ui datepicker (which I can warmly recommend). Easy to use and great looking: https://jqueryui.com/datepicker/

Comment: Yeah sorry if that affects this? Im absolutely clueless here. I had seen this one but i need a date and time picker for this project im doing. this is just the first one i found thats kind of working for me but its very tempermental

Comment: Well, it affects it because those are two completely different libraries. I'd say, that jquery-ui datepicker (the one I linked too above) is by far the most popular and straight forward one there is. Could you link me to the one you are using?

Comment: I have updated my answer, please have a look and let me know if this works for you.

Comment: Hi, Ive tried this and change the backend.php to
<?php

$_SESSION['input'] = $_POST['input='];
echo ($_SESSION['input']);
?>
to match the javascript variable and im still getting the same error:
Notice: Undefined index: input= in C:\wamp\www\gp\backend.php on line 12

Comment: @NiamhMacGualraic Do you have `session_start();` at the very top (first line after the opening <?php tag) in both documents? AJAX needs the receiver document to have `session_start();` in it to be able to manipulate/read session variables. But also the sender needs this... in fact, any document that handles session variables needs it.

Comment: Yes, this is all i have in the backend.php file:
<?php
session_start();
$_SESSION['input'] = $_POST['input1'];
echo ($_SESSION['input']);
?>
do i need anything else?

Comment: Your `$_POST` should only contain  `$_POST['input']`, not  _$_POST['input1']_  neither  _$_POST['input=']_

Comment: Should the $_POST['input'] be holding the value of
data: 'input='?
I have changed the Post variable now but neither seem to work?

Comment: It should be like this `$_SESSION['input'] = $_POST['input'];`

Comment: I have edited my original code so you can see what im currently working with, 
Im also using this in my header:
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
does this have to be in the backend.php also?
also does it matter where the backend.php file is saved?

Comment: @entiendoNull apologies, i did update to your exaple earlier but found it messed the datepicker up a bit i will edit it again now but the outcome was the same

Comment: Is there a way on this where i could send anyone both php pages so that someone could run them and see for themselves? It may appear clearer?

Comment: @NiamhMacGualraic, I've updated my post with a complete guide. Please have a look.

Comment: @entiendoNull, thank you for this, the reason i could not make mine as similar to yours is because mine is an inline jquery picker. apart from this though everything is exactly the same? and the both files are in the same folder. Would you recommend anything else i coould try?

Comment: Add alert(handler.getDate()); on a line just before $.ajax(). What is alerted? I have also updated my post with your datepicker settings.

Comment: Again your datepicker wasnt working with my jquery but i put alert(input); before the ajax call and got this: Tue Mar 31 2015 10:00:00 GMT+0100 (GMT Daylight Time)

Comment: however console.log(input); is above the alert(input); and it doesnt seem to be producing anything?

Answer (score 0):

Should you using jquery cookies too([Jquery Cookies](http://plugins.jquery.com/cookie/)).. So, after you call ajax and success, you will get return session from passing your backend.php, and then that result you store to jquery cookies. After that, you can using cookies for next progress..

Answer (score -1):

Try:

```
<script>
jQuery(function($) {
    $(document).on('click', '#btn_input', function(){ // edit here
        var input = $('*[name=date2]').handleDtpicker('getDate');
        console.log(input);
        jQuery.ajax({
            url: 'backend.php',
            type: 'POST',
            data: {
                'input': input,
            },
            dataType : 'json',
            success: function(data, textStatus, xhr) {
                console.log(data); // do with data e.g success message
            },
            error: function(xhr, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                console.log(textStatus.reponseText);
            }
        });
    });
});
</script>
```

Does this work? If not, what's value of `input` in your console?

Comment: I tried this and the only error im recieving is the same:

Undefined index: input1 in C:\wamp\www\gp\backend.php on line 3

Comment: Apologies, i just change the name of:
data: {
            'input1': input
        },
to ensure the error was with the posted variable and not the session variable.

Comment: So what's outputting `console.log(input)`?

Comment: I dont see anything other than that error on the backend.php page?

Comment: I was talking about the console in your page making the ajax call.

Comment: I've written `console.log(input)`. This should output something in the console when you click on `#btn_input`.

Comment: yes ive included that but nothing seems to be coming from it?

Comment: Can we have the HTML of the button that triggers the `Ajax` call?

Comment: <input type="button" class="btn" id="btn_input" value="Confirm">

Comment: The button is there on page load, its just html on the page

Comment: So if you get an actual response from your Ajax call, there's no way `console.log(input)` outputs nothing.

Comment: I know, I really cant figure it out, this is for uni so im not sure what to do next. Does anyone know of any other date and time pickers i might have better luck with, although i dont know if the picker is the problem im not sure what else to do?

Comment: Is there a way on this where i could send anyone both php pages so that someone could run them and see for themselves? It may appear clearer?